# Xcode shows different provisioning profile when exporting the application

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am running into some strange issue here and I am not sure it's Xcode or it's me not understanding what provisioning profiles really are and how they work.

I have multiple iOS applications and different provisioning profiles (each application has its own profile). I set up the profiles in Xcode but when I want to export the application (all of them are enterprise application), Xcode shows different profile.

Moreover, lately I worked on 2 apps, A and B. When I wanted to export application A, it showed up the profile for application B and the other way around, even though in Xcode I set up the proper profiles.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So both profiles created using same account or different? Also You try to quit the xcode and set it again. Verify are you using different bundle identifiers for both apps

Comment: Yup. In fact all of them are on the same account. And yes, I did restart Xcode and set them up again. Same for the bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 7 for exporting ipa it will ask you to select the development team. In your case it will show same team. At the time of exporting no way you can select profile. Use separate bundle identifiers if you want to install both apps in same device.

Comment: Well, I select the team and all apps have different bundle identifiers (com.company_name.developer_name.app_name). It puzzle me the fact the PP are wrong. I can export without any issue but with different PP...

Comment: Oh, is it OK to use a single provisioning profile with wildcard for application id (AdHocProfile.*) for all applications? We had a single profile until it expired and Xcode "fixed it" for us by generating multiple profiles.